# addEventListener not working... one more

Tags: javascript

I am seeing many addEventListener issues posted here. I have one more. If anyone feels it is duplicate, please go ahead. ok, here is my code. Not able to figure out what's wrong?

```
<body>
<a href="#">Apple</a>
<a href="#">Banana</a>
<a href="#">Carrot</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

window.onload = function(){

    //let's listen to the click event of our links
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i=0;i<links.length;i++){
        var link = links[i];
        link.addEventListener("click", "fnLinkClicked", false); 
    }

    function fnLinkClicked(){
        alert(this.innerText);
    }
}

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that I'm using IE 11

Comment: please tell us what the expected behaviour is

Comment: And also to specify what exactly isn't working...

Comment: What is the issue? Event handler not firing? Exception throwing?

Comment: The string "fnLinkClicked" is not a function, I think you want without quotes.

Comment: Hi all, thank you. As randomusername and Alexander pointed out, the culprit was the double quote in my function name. I removed it, it's working fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
link.addEventListener("click", "fnLinkClicked", false);
```

The second argument should be a function, not a string:

```
link.addEventListener("click", fnLinkClicked, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have quotes around `"fnLinkClicked"`, functions are first class objects in javascript

Comment: thanks...sometimes silly mistakes can really bug us :).

Comment: @Jonasw there are programming languages where you can't just pass a function around (they're not first class objects) so you gotta use quirky hacks that involve passing the name of the function as a string...